# HC-05 Bluetooth Serial Sometime getting wrong value

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

I have Connected HC-05 with Arduino UNO I'm sending Integer value Example:

```
Send           Receive
10             10
11             0
15             15
18             2541
```

Sometime getting correct Data and sometime getting wrong Data.

Global:

```
//Bluetooth
#define BLUETOOTH_SPEED 9600
SoftwareSerial bluetooth(10, 11);
```

Setup:

```
bluetooth.begin(BLUETOOTH_SPEED);
```

Loop:

```
if (bluetooth.available() > 0) {
    integerValue = 0;
    while (bluetooth.available() > 0) {
      byte incoming = bluetooth.read();
      //Serial.println(incoming);
      if (incoming >= '0' && incoming <= '9') {
        integerValue = (integerValue * 10) + (incoming - '0');
        //delay(5);
      }
    }
    bluetooth.flush();
    Serial.println(integerValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

SoftwareSerial on Arduino is essentially a half-duplex type of communication. You may have dedicated transmit and receive pins, but the same timer is used for transmitting and receiving. So you can't do both transmitting and receiving work on the SoftwareSerial object at the same time.

This part of your code makes me think that you are transmitting something inside some other part of the code.

```
bluetooth.flush();
```

If you are, you will have to implement some form of flow control to ensure that you are not transmitting and receiving something on SoftwareSerial object at the same time.

Comment: Um not transmitting and receiving both. only for Receiving data... Sending from Android Apps via Bluetooth and Receiving with Arduino... Should  I not use "bluetooth.flush();"

Comment: I am not 100% certain if removing bluetooth.flush would help or not. But I do know for sure that you don't need it.